# Requiring a file from a higher hierachy

Tags: function, syntax, lua, require

This maybe a very, very simple question to ask, and I am sorry if it is a waste of time but I haven't gotten anywhere with it. I am trying to access a file in a higher hierarchy than the file I am working with. I have been searching for a while now and this is as far as I got with it:

```
package.path = package.path .. ";C:\\Users\\%username%\\Desktop\\Folders\\Programming\\Lua\\Projects\\MyFramework"
require "main"
```

I've also added a os.execute('pause') at the end of it so I can make sure it passes without errors.

How can I require() a file from a higher hierarchy than the file that is trying to require it?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a placeholder for the module name in the modified path, probably something like `\\?.lua` at the end.